# Is the array undefined because component is rendering before data is loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've imported an array of objects from a seperate js file into my main app.js file in react. I want to map through the array and pass the object values as props to a seperate component. When I run this code the pupils array is coming back as undefined.

I'm new to react and js, this is a learning project I'm working on usings functional components.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { pupils } from "./pupils"
import PupilCard from "./Components/PupilCard";


const App = () => {



 return (<div>
    {pupils.map(pupil => 
    <PupilCard 
        firstname={pupil.firstname} 
        surname={pupil.surname}
        photo={pupil.photo}
        behaviourPoints={pupil.behaviourPoints}
        assessmentOne={pupil.assessmentOne}
        assessmentTwo={pupil.assessmentTwo}
        assessmentThree={pupil.assessmentThree}  
     />)}

 </div>)}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

pupils.js example

```
const pupils = [
    {
        firstname: "Name",
        surname: "Name",
        photo:"./assets/pupilPhotos/user.png",
        behaviourPoints: 25,
        assessmentOne:70,
        assessmentTwo:60,
        assessmentThree:80        
    },
 {
        firstname: "Name",
        surname: "Name",
        photo:"./assets/pupilPhotos/user.png",
        behaviourPoints: 25,
        assessmentOne:70,
        assessmentTwo:60,
        assessmentThree:80        
    }]
```

Comment: have you exported `pupils` array?

Comment: `import { pupils } from "./pupils"` means you need `export { pupils };` at the end of your file.

Comment: use `export const pupils = [...]`

Comment: you can import only something that has been exported. You should have an error in your linter or something like that saying that ' there is no exported member pupils ' or something similar.

Comment: @MihaiT `pupil.js`s, `export` is `{}`, so `pupils` is going to be `undefined`. I don't think the linter will catch that. You do get a `pupils is assigned a value but never used` in `pupils.js` though.

Comment: Thanks guys, I knew it was probably something simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use "pupils" this way it must be exported as 
`export const pupils = ...`.
Maybe you exporting it like `export default...` then it should be imported without destructuring 
`import pupils from './pupils'`
[this cheatsheet may help you to better understand imports/exports](https://hackernoon.com/import-export-default-require-commandjs-javascript-nodejs-es6-vs-cheatsheet-different-tutorial-example-5a321738b50f)

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your array in pupils.js in order to import it in another file. If you use 'export default' you have to remove the curly braces around pupils in the import statement, Or you can just export as named and keep the curly braces in the import.
That should do it.